# Lookup using two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following problem to solve - I have one excel file with two relevant sheets:

1. first sheet contains the data with multiple columns - however, only two columns are relevant here, namely category and subcategory
2. second sheet contains the mapping between old and new **combinations** of categories and subcategories.
   So we have all the possible combinations of the two that come up in different cases listed in one pair of columns and next to that are columns defining the combinations of categories and subcategories to be mapped to. It is a "one to one" relation, one old and one new combination per line, so that part is straightforward. This sheet is basically a look-up table for mapping of the values in the first sheet to new ones.
   Now, since I am pretty inexperienced with excel functions, I am wondering where to start looking, which function(s) in excel could do the work here if any? Any additional tips are very welcome. Thank you.
   Here are the screenshots of the two sheets:

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2 - lookup table]

So, to give an example in order to be more clear, if you look at the two screenshots - if we have a row in  the input file in which the category is "Asset management" AND the subcategory is "Custodian transfer", the function should rename that to "Change of custodian" for the category and "Other" for the subcategory.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this should work:

```
=XLOOKUP(B3&C3,A12:A16&B12:B16,C12:D16)
```

Here, we are joining the values in column B and C in the first parameter (i.e. `B3&C3`). In row 3, that gives us the value "asset managementcustodian transfer". This is the `lookup_value` for `XLOOKUP`. We are looking for that value in the array that is formed by joining column A and column B from the lookup table (i.e. `A12:A16&B12:B16`). If we join every row together, that array looks like this:

```
ASSET MANAGEMENTCUSTODIAN TRANSFER
ASSET MANAGEMENTFUNDS CHANGES
BACKLOGBACKLOG
BENEFITCANCELLATION
BENEFITDEATH CLAIM
```

The `lookup_value` is found on the first row of that array. The next parameter is the return array `C12:D16`. For the lookup_value, found on the first row of the array, this will return the values in `C12:D12`.

[image]